# Array.prototype.slice, can't get 'slice' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok so I have some code that brings data from a server in the form of an javascript array.

I have been looking into prototype and seen that you could select parts of the array using slice, but I can't seem to find out how it works even when looking at the exampled.

So far I have a module.js that loads the data and directs to my index page

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        apptoken: apptoken
    }
});

var promise1 = $.get(dbidApplication, {
    a: "dbpage",
    pagename: "index.html"
});


var promise2 = $.get(dbidTable, {
    act: "API_GenResultsTable",
    query: "{3.EX." + kRid + "}",
    jsa: 1,
    options: "num-1",
});


$.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(templateArgs, dataArgs) {
    var template = templateArgs[0];
    var markup = Mustache.render(template, qdb_data);
    document.write(markup);
    $("#formContents").html(markup);
});
```

My index.html page is completely blank except for the

```
var stringit = qdb_data.toString();
var stationid = stringit.slice(4);

console.log(stationid);
```

on the console it shows my stringit and in 4 there is data, so I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong...All in all I am attempting to use the array to fill in a template.

This is what I am returned from my query earlier

```
var qdb_data = new Array();

 qdb_data[0] = new Array();
 qdb_data[0][0] = "VL14799- FT5850";
 qdb_data[0][1] = "05-13-2015";
 qdb_data[0][2] = "";
 qdb_data[0][3] = "TANK PROPANE";
 qdb_data[0][4] = "PLANT";
 qdb_data[0][5] = "PROPANE";
 qdb_data[0][6] = "TANK 31 PROPANE";
 qdb_data[0][7] = "PLANT";
 qdb_data[0][8] = "TANK 31 PROPANE";
 qdb_data[0][9] = "PROPANE";
 qdb_data[0][10] = "PROPANE";
 qdb_data[0][11] = "100 PSI";
 qdb_data[0][12] = "59 F";
 qdb_data[0][13] = "411";
 qdb_data[0][14] = "";
 qdb_data[0][15] = "";
 qdb_data[0][16] = "BR";
```

Comment: Note: Using `document.write()` after the document has already finished loading will first reset it to have no contents before writing the argument.

Comment: That's not `Array.prototype.slice`, that's `String.prototype.slice`.

Comment: Why are you turning a 2-D array into a string before trying to use `.slice()` on it?  That is making no sense to me at all.  You've shown what the `qdb_data` array looks like.  Please show the exact data structure you want to achieve after a `.slice()` call.  If you want a sub-set of the contents in array form as the result, you would NOT convert to a string first.  Also, it's not clear at all what the first code block in your question has to do with the question.  There's no reference to `.slice()` in that code block.

Comment: What is expected result a) calling `.toString();` ? ; b)   `var stationid = stringit.slice(4);` ?

Comment: @billyonecan: Your statement is correct as far as it goes, but String.prototype.slice() is also a function. It's not the function the question is asking about, but shouldn't calling it produce a different error?

Comment: _"took that out for now"_ Took what out ?

Comment: Ok so, I don't need to have it as a string? Because all the examples I've seen were in strings, but maybe I was just looking at it the wrong way. Also, I was looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice when I was trying to figure out how slice works, but again I haven't worked with it before so I may be using it wrong.     I took out the document.write in the module.js

Comment: As far as what is expected, I am trying to get it to where I am getting the value for adb_data[0][4] stored into a variable so I can use it later with something like handlebars.js so stationid should be PLANT in this case

Comment: Just do this `var stationid = qdb_data[0].slice(4,5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript both array and string have slice method.What you actually want is the array slice and what you have is string slice. JavaScript will perform the slice based on whether the variable is a string or array automatically.So in order to get the value at the 4th index do the following.

```
var stationid = qdb_data[0].slice(4,5);
```